# Can I use Arrays.copyOf to make a defensive copy of a two dimensional array?

Tags: java

As far as I understand we can use [`java.util.Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) to copy a two dimensional array, but is it safe to use it for defensive copying (assuming elements are immutable)? E.g.

```
void setValues(Integer[][] arr) {
    this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.copyOf` uses `System.arraycopy` internally, so no, it is not appropriate for making defensive (deep) copies (not for mutable types at least).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a deep copy.  `arr` looks like this (mocking up memory addresses):

```
@0x01 [
  @0x10 [1,2],
  @0x20 [2,3],
  @0x30 [4,5],
]
```

When you make a copy with `Arrays.copyOf`, you get a new outer array, so `this.arr` will be:

```
@0x02 [
  @0x10 [1,2],
  @0x20 [2,3],
  @0x30 [4,5],
]
```

If you want to be sure your 2d array won't change, you do this:

```
this.arr = new Integer[arr.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    this.arr[i] = Arrays.copyOf(arr[i], arr[i].length);
}
```

Now *this* is only safe because `Integer` is immutable.  If it was something more complex, you'd have to work out how to safely copy *that*, which might involve more copies.  Java doesn't provide a free deep-copy for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not **deep** copy its **shallow** copy.

It copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will contain identical values.

```
2771    public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
2772        T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
2773            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
2774            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
2775        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
2776                         Math.min(original.length, newLength));
2777        return copy;
2778    }
```

[Code reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOf%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,int%29) - open jdk 6-b14

Comment: I would reference the overload without `newType`, so the code snippet is less cluttered.

Comment: That would not be generic solution for all `Object Type`.

Comment: That makes no sense. The OP isn't even using this overload. But it's your answer.

Comment: No. you get me wrong, it is just a reference of orginal `Arrays.copyOf`, I have not overloaded anything.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize one method was calling the other one.

Comment: yap man, Internally it is called, [check the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOf%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%29)